# Unable to load userform

Tags: vba, excel

I am unable to load an userform on opening workbook. Object is Workbook, procedure is Open and have this code in ThisWorkbook.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open() 
    frmWelcome.Show 
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you certain that you've named the userform properly? Double check in the properties window next to the (Name) line. Perhaps you only renamed the caption line?

Comment: You need to make sure Macros are enabled. Also, there are / have been some bugs in the workbook_open in some version(s) of Excel, so it may help if you post what version you're using.

Comment: Thank you for responding guys. I double checked name and it is rightly used.

Comment: I am using Excel 2010 version. Also, I have other macros in the same workbook and they are working fine. So macros are enabled.

Comment: I will upload it to expirebox later. previously, userform was loading as soon as i opened workbook. but now it is not working. I do not know why. Also, my workbook is password protected. is it a problem to load userform?

Comment: Interesting thing happened just now... I renamed the file and am getting userform as soon as I open workbook now. the first userform is like an agreement where there are command buttons to 'agree' and 'disagree'.

Answer (score 0):

Here's some code that I use, placed in a module called mMain with the form called fForm. I suggest that you start fresh, with something like this, make sure that works, and proceed from there, changing one thing at a time.

```
Option Explicit
Public dLog As fForm
Sub main()
Set dLog = New fForm
dLog.Show vbModeless  'doesn't have to be modeless
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much Tony! I will work on this... I might need help with one more macro on random numbers.. I am working on it. Stay tuned!